# Java : 2 lines angle finding?

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm using Java and slick2D.

The Class:Line is referenced from : org.newdawn.slick.geom.Line

My question is how can I find out how many degrees is the angle that concluded two lines.

Example:

```
Line ln1 = new Line(0,1,0,3);
Line ln2 = new Line(1,0,3,0);
```

The angles that ln1 and ln2 are concluding are : 90,90 degrees - the two lines are perpendicular.

I hope you could help me :D

Comment: please can you explain "concluding"?

Comment: Assuming that the constructor is of the form `Line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`, and it represents a line segment between the points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, your example has two line segments that don't intersect.

The extensions of those lines would intersect at `(0,0)`, and angle between those two extended lines would indeed be 90 degrees. Is the question about determining an angle between arbitrary lines? or determining if they intersect? Or something else?

Comment: well i translated google but what i mean is that i want to find the angle that the two lines cross each other

Comment: Well in my program im sure in that the two lines are crossing.I just need to find the angle between them.

Comment: The two lines cross at 90 degrees as you say. So your question is not clear. What do you want from us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code calculates the angle between the two lines in radians:

```
double angle1 = Math.atan2(ln1.getY1() - ln1.getY2(), ln1.getX1() - ln1.getX2());
double angle2 = Math.atan2(ln2.getY1() - ln2.getY2(), ln2.getX1() - ln2.getX2());
double desiredAngle = angle1 - angle2
```